# Existence of a linear form sending a non zero vector to non zero scalar.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $E$ be a real $n-$dimensional space. Let $x$ be a non zero vector of $E$. I want to show that there exists a linear fomr $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\not = 0$.

My try is to take a basis $(e_1,\cdots,e_n)$ of $E$. Then $x=a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n$ for some scalars $a_1,\cdots,a_n$. Now since $x$ is not zero then there exists at least one of the $a_i$ that is not zero. I thought about $f(x)=a_1+\cdots + a_n$ but this can be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $f= x_i$, the linear map which maps every vector to its $i$th coordinate in that basis.

Comment: you mean $f(x)=a_i$ ? this can be zero of course.

Comment: What? You chose $i$ so that the $i$th coordinate of $x$ in that basis was not zero...

Comment: Choose $i$ such that $a_i\neq 0$, then take $f=x_i$, simple as that.

Comment: Oh i see, how i missed that !! thank you very much..